# ASP.NET permissions issues

Tags: asp.net

Im using Windows Server 2008, IIS7, .NET 4 and when I use the FileUpload control to save a file to a directory I get :

Access to the path 'C:\xxx\Websites\CMS\Admin\test' is denied.

I have given the test folder full control permissions for NETWORK SERVICE but it makes no difference.

I have given full control to the   Everyone  user but makes no difference.

It might have something to do with the fact that up in the CMS folder there is a MVC web application and in the CMS\Admin folder there is a web forms web application.  It is the web forms web application that is trying to upload the file and getting the permissions error.

Can anyone offer a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running your application in Medium Trust?  Medium Trust does not allow file IO outside of it's own virtual path hierarchy.

Check the web.config for a `<trust level="Medium" ...` element.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, the  trust element isn't mentioned in the web.config file at all.
But anyway the test folder is a sub folder within the web application so its not outside the virtual path hierarchy is it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Application Pool that your site is running under and make sure that it is running as NetworkService instead of PoolIdentity.